# Blackmagic Decklink Interfaces for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, interface, video-capture, directshow.net

I am searching for interfaces for a decklink video device for C# .Net using DirectShowLib.Net.

It seems, there are available, because they are used here:
[blackmagic SDK in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355930/blackmagic-sdk-in-c-sharp)
Unfortunately there is no information, which library is used and the comment which ask for more information was ignored.

But I don't have an idea, where to find them. Would be nice, if someone can give me an hint.

Answer (score 5):

SDK is available off Blackmagic website: [Blackmagic Design SDKs](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/support/sdks/). The sample code is mostly C++, however a part is in C# as well. The SDK has all IDL files on it and you can convert the interfaces into .NET compatible shape.

Answer (score 2):

There are also third-party SDKs available, that may be more effective depending on your task. Such as this [SDK for ingest & playout](http://www.medialooks.com/mplatform/).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting to an old thread. Maybe someone finds it useful.

There is a DeckLink .NET wrapper at [GitHub](https://github.com/simongh/DeckLink.net) but I find it little use as C# Interop (wrapper) is automatically created if you reference the C:\Program Files (x86)\Blackmagic Design\Blackmagic Desktop Video\DeckLinkAPI.dll in Visual Studio.